# Can't disable auto-download in version 4.3

Tags: photoeditorsdk

My config is:

```
self.editor = new $window.PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
    container,
    responsive: true,
    license: JSON.stringify(sdkLicenseData),
    assets: {
        baseUrl: '/dist/photoeditorsdk/assets/',
    },
    editor: {
        image: img,
    },
    style: {
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
    },
    enableExport: true,
    export: {
        type: $window.PhotoEditorSDK.ImageFormat.IMAGE,
        quality: 1.0,
        download: false,
    },
});
```

I'm able to detect export being clicked by:

```
self.editor.on('export', (newUrl) => {
```

.. but it still downloads the image. How can this be disabled?

I've also tried:

```
self.editor.on('export', (newUrl) => {
                            self.editor.export(false)
                                .then((data) => {
                                    const foo = 1;
                                });
```

...but again, by the time I execute the 2nd line, an image has already been downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `export` field here must be inside the `editor` option, e.g.,

```
self.editor = new $window.PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
container,
responsive: true,
license: JSON.stringify(sdkLicenseData),
assets: {
    baseUrl: '/dist/photoeditorsdk/assets/',
},
editor: {
    image: img,
    export: {
      type: $window.PhotoEditorSDK.ImageFormat.IMAGE,
      quality: 1.0,
      download: false,
  }
},
style: {
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
},
enableExport: true
})
```

Then is should work.